# Error occurred while processing mail

Tags: email, thunderbird

I cannot get my email using email programs;
Thunderbird or Claws.

I get the following error message using Claws.

"[2023-09-11 15:45:31] POP< +OK POP3 server ready.
[2023-09-11 15:45:31] POP> STLS
[2023-09-11 15:45:31] POP< -ERR not authorized to use STLS command
*** couldn't start STARTTLS session"
*** Error occurred while processing mail.

I get the following message when using Thunderbird.

"Error occurred while processing mail:
-ERR not authorized to use STLS command".

Emails are available thru the isp web sight.

Comment: It appears that you may have chosen incorrect options when setting up the account in the email clients.

Comment: I have been using the same parameters for years before the problem occured.

Comment: Options restored to both Claws and Thunderbird Claws now works Thunderbird doe not.